# socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known, while sending mail in python

Tags: python-2.7, supervisord

```
    smtp_ssl_host = 'smtp.webfaction.com'
    smtp_ssl_port = ***
    username = '******'
    password = '******'
    sender = '*******'
    targets = [' ******', '******', '*****', '*******', '********', 
    '**********', '**********']
    msg = MIMEText(message)
    msg['Subject'] = 'Device Status Information'
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(targets)
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, targets, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

now I am getting the exception like

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/bin/ping.py", line 271, in <module>
       thread1 = myThread(in_data)
     File "/usr/local/bin/ping.py", line 128, in __init__
       status_check = self.status_check(lane=lane, direction=direction, anpr=anpr_state, axle=axle_state, camera=camera_state, profiler=profiler_state, user=user_state, weighbridge=weighbridge_state, tollcontrol=tollcontrol_state, timestamp=tt)
     File "/usr/local/bin/ping.py", line 221, in status_check
       self.send_email(message=message)
     File "/usr/local/bin/ping.py", line 256, in send_email
       server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 793, in __init__
       SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
       (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
       self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 798, in _get_socket
       new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
       for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

In the above exception **self.status_check(lane=lane, direction=direction, anpr=anpr_state, axle=axle_state, camera=camera_state, profiler=profiler_state, user=user_state, weighbridge=weighbridge_state, tollcontrol=tollcontrol_state, timestamp=tt)** is a function where I am calling another function **self.send_email(message=message)** with message as a parameter and in **self.send_email(message=message)** function I wrote email sending code where I got above exception.

**Note:** All the above code I am running in supervisor*

*It worked perfectly in localhost but getting exception while running in supervisor*

Answer (score 1):

1- why you use smtp.SMTP_SSL while you can use smtp.SMTP?

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.webfaction.com', 587)
```

2- Why you don't start TLS Protocol :

```
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
```

3- there is an example:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
targets = ['facebook@facebook.com', 'msn@msn.com' , 'gmail@gmail.com', 'hotmail@hotmail.com' , 'yahoo@yahoo.com']
server = 'smtp.webfaction.com'
port = 587;
server = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)
msgbody = 'This Is an Device Status Information'
msg = MIMEText(msgbody, 'plain', 'utf-8')
msg['Subject'] = Header('Device Status Information', 'utf-8')
msg['From'] = Header(sender, 'utf-8')
target = []
target.append(','.join(map(str, targets)))
msg['To'] = Header(target, 'utf-8')
txt = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(sender,  target, txt)
server.quit()
```